# How do you pad a string to a length = n with consecutivley randomly generated characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random, char

I'm trying to take a user input string, the string cannot be over 70 chars from the user but once padded, the total string will be 100 chars in length.

However, I must make up the rest of the 100 chars of the string using randomly generated letters. THe issue I'm having is that I'm generating the same singular character and then padding it to meet the 100 char limit. How do I make it so that the string contains random characters?

Example of what I want:

user input: `ABC`

desired output: `ABCJ4RLKDIJHSJRLWOINGHZXNROQUTJHLOUHFPSNDUVMFHTQAQ` etc up to 100 chars.

What I'm getting is the following:

user input: `ABC`

output: `ABCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT` etc up to 100 chars.

Here is my code:

```
text = input("Enter your string: ")
if len(text) > 70: exit("Char limit cannot exceed 70")

print(text.ljust(100, random.choice(string.ascii_letters)))
```

Comment: Simple approach can be a while-loop which checks if the final string length isn't reached yet and in the loop add only one random character.

Comment: Can you think of a rule that tells you how many random characters you need? Can you think of a way to generate that many characters and concatenate them? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you only want upper case letters? If so, you should randomly choose from `string.ascii_uppercase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can add that random function inside the loop to get your desired output and answer by enzo was accurate**

I have edited your code in a *simple way* that *i know* but you can edit it for your wish.

```
import string
import random
a = ""
while True:
    text = input("Enter your string: ")
    if len(text) > 70: 
        print("Char limit cannot exceed 70")
        continue
    else:
        for i in range (100 - len(text)):
            a += (random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
            
        break
print(text + a)
```

I hope this is useful :)

Comment: I appreciate this, it seems more logical to follow from my background than enzo's but both get the job done and I thank you both for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

well, `ljust` is not the tool you want, it takes a *single* character and pads with that.

This is really not hard to achieve: subtract the length you have from the length you want, generate many random characters, and append them to the string.

This is really a basic exercise in python, and if there's questions about how to do any of these steps, you'd be very well-advised to spend a little more time with the official python.org introduction. It's not like learning how to code a loop will not safe you time today.

Answer (score 0):

That was a freaking nice attempt! You were close, but you can just use string concatenation instead of `ljust` [as Marcus Müller explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386292/9997212):

```py
import random
import string

text = input("Enter your string: ")
size = len(text)
if size > 70: 
    exit("Char limit cannot exceed 70")

# Append to the end of `text` with `100 - size` (the remaining) random chars
result = text + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(100 - size))

assert len(result) == 100
assert result.startswith(text)
print(result)
```

Comment: Could use `random.choices` here. `result = text + ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=100-size)`

Comment: This does not allow repetitions.

Comment: `sample` doesn't allow repeititions, [choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) does.